# Pass js variable to form action url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I am doing it the wrong way?

I have a form that when submitted, should send the user to a URL depending on the input.

e.g If the users inputs '2', the URL should be `books/itemView?id=2`

I have created a `var = id`, which takes the search input box data. Is it possible to add this variable to my current form action? Perhaps there is a more efficient way?

My current code is as follows;

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo URL; ?>books/itemView?id=" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" id="demo"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var id = $('#search').val();

});
```

Quite new to JS so any help appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `GET` for the purpose of retrieving data. And if you do so, the query string would be `?search=searchVal`. Just change the name attribute to `id` for the text input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS should be

```
$('#search').on('submit', function() {
    var id = $('#demo').val();
    var formAction = $('#search').attr('action');
    $('#search').attr('action', formAction + id);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add another var after formAction + id (eg if I had another hidden input val names isbn?). Something like formAction + id + isbn

Comment: formAction + id + '&isbn=' + isbn

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can try with that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $form = $('#search');
  var id = $form.val();
  var $search = $('#demo');
  var originalAction = $search.attr('action');
  $form.on('submit', function() {
    $search.attr('action', originalAction + id);
  });
});
```

Before submitting the form, jQuery's `on('submit', handler)` function executes the code in `handler` modifying the attribute action that you want.

`originalAction` variable stores the content of the `action` attribute that was partially generated in php, then you append your `id` dynamically created with js.

Answer (score 1):

If they enter 2 in the search input then your id will be appended to your url like:

```
url?search=2
```

So maybe you want to change the name of your search input to id or add another input field.

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo URL; ?>books/itemView" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id" id="demo"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That should be all you need no jquery or javascript necessary.

When you submit it should result in:

```
books/itemView?id=2(or whatever is in the search/id input when you click submit)
```

Comment: should the method bet 'get' then?

Comment: Yes, if you want the values to be appended to the URL.

Comment: @johnny_s Yes if you want it to be appended to url. Otherwise it is still passed you just can't see it in the url.