# How to apply a JS variable to a Laravel Form Action

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I need to pass an AJAX variable into my view such that the `form action` executes correctly. Using Laravel 5.4. and my (abbreviated) view looks like this:

```
<div id="product_form"  class="form-horizontal">

    {{ Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@update_product', // PRODUCT_ID MUST GO HERE]) }}


    <div class=" form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">{{ Form::label('product_name', 'Product Name:') }}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{{ Form::text('product_name',null) }}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{{ Form::label('product_id', 'Product Code') }}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{{ Form::text('product_id', null) }}</div>
    </div>
```

My Ajax function is passing all the values into the form fields correctly, however I am struggling to get the `product_id` into the correct place in the action statement. Laravel expects to see a variable.

Ajax Code (abbreviated):

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
        var product_id = ( ui.item.value );

        $.ajax({
            url: "product_fullsearch/"+product_id,
            dataType: "json",
            type:"GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#product_name').val(data[0].product_name);
                $('#product_id').val(data[0].product_id);
                $("#supplier_name").val(data[0].supplier_name);
                $("#supplier_id").val(data[0].supplier_id);
            }
        });//END AJAX

    }
```

I saw this [Pass JS variable to form action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092501/987051) on SO and gave it a go, but I could not get it to work in a Laravel context.

What am I dong wrong ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an alternative way of solving the problem:

Instead of attempting to pass a variable into the `form action`, I changed the Route such that it no longer required an `id`. Then in the controller I simply pull the `id` value from the `$request` array like this:

`$id = $request->product_id;`

I this way the update works:

```
 $id = $request->product_id;

    Product::updateOrCreate(array('product_id' => $id),
        array(
            'product_name' => $request->product_name,
            'product_id'=>$id,
        ));
```

I hope this helps someone else.